# i tried deleting a gpg key and i got an error

Tags: apt, ppa, error-handling

i just used sudo apt-key del
then i got this from apt

> Hit:1 ttp://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Hit:2 ttp://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
> Hit:3 ttp://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
> Hit:4 ttps://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Hit:5 ttp://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
> Get:6 ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
> Hit:7 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Hit:8 ttps://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
> Err:7 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1EE2FF37CA8DA16B
> Hit:9 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Hit:10 ttps://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-security InRelease
> Hit:11 ttps://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-updates InRelease
> Hit:12 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Hit:13 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/ozmartian/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Fetched 114 kB in 3s (41.1 kB/s)
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> All packages are up to date.
> W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1EE2FF37CA8DA16B
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1EE2FF37CA8DA16B
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

dont mind the missing h's in the output, the website wouldnt let me post more that 8 links without 10 reputation

Answer (score -1):

y-ppa-manager fixed it, after reinstalling it and deleting it using it my problem was solved, still not sure what was wrong